# Would it be sensible for the House Democrats to vote for McCarthy as speaker?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, speaker

It is my understanding that McCarthy is struggling to get elected, because some more extreme Republicans regard him as 'too moderate'. Doesn't that mean that the choice is basically McCarthy or someone more extreme? In that case wouldn't it be sensible for the House Democrats to vote for McCarthy since, even if not really, he's still more in line with Democratic policies than the others?

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing. The hardline Republicans have been threatening to "straitjacket" McCarthy and prevent him from doing anything should he get elected, which you'd imagine would benefit the Democrats more than it would the Republicans.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would voting for a US House Speaker candidate from a majority party be "taboo" and punishable if you're a member of a minority party?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/77182/why-would-voting-for-a-us-house-speaker-candidate-from-a-majority-party-be-tabo)

Comment: @JonathanReez I feel that this is a different question as that is asking about a single or couple of members voting for the other party while this appears to be asking for the minority party as a whole.

Comment: @JonathanReez This is definitely not a duplicate. Good question @op!

Comment: Upvote for the logical game-theoretic strategy here. (I'm a math nerd.) Maybe you should run for office yourself?

Comment: I think people tend to overestimate the importance of the technical aspects of politics compared to the softer aspects of politics. Yes, if this were a rational choice theory class the Democrats would be voting for McCarthy, but the messaging of voting in a perfectly uniform fashion has value in its own right.

Comment: The question is good because it is complicated.  Of course, I have the advantage over the previous commentators of hindsight, but for me the question was never "McCarthy or someone more extreme" but instead what does McCarthy have to give to get his speakership.  From that POV, it might make sense for the Democrats to give McCarthy votes if he was going to give something in return but he was not so he got nothing.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

"Never interrupt your enemy when he is making a mistake." ([Attributed](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2010/07/06/never-interfere/) to Napoleon Bonaparte)

The Democrats, by refusing to assist the Republicans in electing a speaker of the house, highlight the disunity of the Republican Party. While the Republican Party is in disunity, they cannot enact any legislative efforts that the Democratic minority might object to, so this also achieves the goal of stopping Republican-supported bills from passing.

Additionally, there are no rules stating that the Speaker of the House has to be from the majority party. The Speaker traditionally is from the majority party because the majority party typically has enough votes to install them. So there is also a counter-question of whether it would be sensible for House Republicans to vote for Jeffries as a way to end the standoff, as he is currently the one closest to the required 218 votes. That is the outcome the Democrats want the most, and they are willing to wait and see if it happens.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141861/discussion-on-answer-by-thegs-would-it-be-sensible-for-the-house-democrats-to-vo).

Comment: Vote for Jeffries?? At the most it would be a "compromise candidate" (like Liz Cheney) and even that would be insane.

Answer (score 62):

McCarthy [may be](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/01/06/politics/maga-politics-consume-kevin-mccarthy/index.html) too moderate for some extremist Republicans, but he's not moderate in the classic sense, not in line with Democratic policies, and his anti-democratic antics may pose a threat not just to Democrats, but to democracy.

Looking at his history as [minority leader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_McCarthy#House_minority_leader): He supported far-right candidates such as Marjorie Taylor Greene and was a loyal Trump ally. He didn't accept the result of the 2020 election, voted against certifying the results, and spread false conspiracy theories about voter fraud. Incendiary remarks like his have been linked to the Jan 6 attack on the capitol and Democrats have called his actions "election subversion".

After what has been described as a "coup" failed, he started distancing himself a bit from the more extreme elements, but objected to an independent investigation into the attack.

---

His [political positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_McCarthy#Political_positions) are opposed to Democratic positions. He opposes abortions, environmentalism, doesn't accept the scientific consensus on climate change, opposes the affordable care act, and opposed DACA.

---

Putting the political differences aside, voting for someone who has a track record of rejecting and fighting to undermine democratic election results out of political considerations would be a danger not only to Democrats, but to democracy.

Given that there are other choices - such as [hoping](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/77535/8062) for moderate Republicans to vote for a Democratic speaker, for Republicans to put up a more moderate Republican speaker to win votes from the Democrats, or to go for an independent speaker and form a coalition government - it's not difficult to see why Democrats wouldn't jump at the chance to vote for McCarthy.

A number of Democrats have signaled that they are open to [making a deal](https://www.thedailybeast.com/republicans-and-democrats-quietly-consider-a-kevin-mccarthy-speaker-deal), but wouldn't support a Republican who objected to the 2020 election results.

Answer (score 15):

Conservative commentator and never-Trumper David Frum, in ["No Tears for Kevin McCarthy,"](https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2023/01/kevin-mccarthy-house-republican-party-speakership/672648/) (*The Atlantic,* 2023-01-05), argues that McCarthy is so compromised that Congress, the country and possibly even the Republicans are likely be better off with someone else, even if that other person is more ideologically conservative. And, indeed, that even with a speaker more ideologically conservative than McCarthy, the house may still end up with a less ideological majority.

> Distaste for the anti-McCarthy faction, however, should not mislead anyone into supporting McCarthy. Very specifically, distaste for the anti-McCarthy faction should not mislead House Democrats into rescuing McCarthy. McCarthy has been frantically signaling for Democratic rescue. Speakers are elected by a majority of the representatives. If enough Democrats were to absent themselves, McCarthy could be elected speaker by the roughly 200 Republicans who do back him. But what’s the affirmative case for such rescue?
>
> If McCarthy becomes speaker now, he will be a weak and precarious one—constantly at the mercy over the next two years of those 20-odd fringe Republicans voting against him this week. McCarthy will appease and accommodate them. When John Boehner was speaker, he dealt with the irreconcilable fringe by building majorities across the aisle. The 2015 budget deal that ended that year’s debt-ceiling crisis passed the House with only 174 Republican votes, augmented by 95 Democratic votes to reach the necessary 218 majority. But if McCarthy survives his present leadership test, he’ll do so only by committing never to repeat Boehner’s example. That commitment will have teeth, too, because McCarthy has reportedly agreed to allow any single disaffected Republican to call for a vote of confidence in his speakership if he displeases them. He has proposed to escape his immediate hostage crisis by handing himself over as a hostage forever.
>
> That’s the beginning of the reason it would be better if he failed to win the speakership. If McCarthy somehow ekes out a win, he will be broken from the beginning—an officeholder who holds only the office, not the power of the office....
>
> It would be better to have a speaker who can deliver than one who cannot, even if that speaker is more ideological than McCarthy. An ideologue can say “Yes” and have it mean something; a speaker who does not command a majority cannot.
>
> By electing a more ideological speaker, Republicans may inadvertently shape a less ideological House majority. Imagine what this House will look like after a McCarthy defeat. Twenty Republican House members will have exposed 200 colleagues to national ridicule for reasons that even those 20 insurgents cannot coherently explain. Are the 200 now likely to follow the 20 into a fight to default on the U.S. debt? To slash American aid to Ukraine and hand the advantage to Russian President Vladimir Putin? To try to impeach President Joe Biden over some QAnon fantasy? To devote the next Congress to waging war on the FBI and other law-enforcement agencies? Or will they more likely say, “That’s enough from you—you have embarrassed us one time too many”?

TLDR: No, it would not be sensible for House Democrats to vote for McCarthy as house speaker. Even if he's personally "still more in line with Democratic policies than the others," he's likely to be compromised in a way that he will do what the Republican extremists ask in order to stay in power.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question asked.

Comment: @IanKemp The line of reasoning is such that *even* Republicans supposedly would be better off without McCarthy, it also applies to Democrats.

Comment: I think it does.  In the negative.  As another answer states, McCarthy is hardly a cuddly teddy bear to the Dems.  As this answer suggests, he may even amplify partisanship, due to his - alleged - incapacity to exercise leadership against the loons in his party.  Not sure I agree with a *more ideological* dude, but he's pretty much prostrated himself to the likes of Gaetz at this point.  Unsuccessfully.

Comment: Ian, the question is, "Wouldn't it be sensible for the House Democrats to vote for McCarthy?" You don't consider, "...distaste for the anti-McCarthy faction should not mislead House Democrats into rescuing McCarthy," i.e., they should not vote for him, to be an answer to that?

Comment: @cjs Frum's argument that McCarthy would be a lame-duck Speaker does not necessarily imply that it would not be *sensible* for Democrats to vote for him as Speaker. A Speaker from the opposition incapable of carrying out their role effectively, is an easy political goal for Dems to repeatedly score - especially when it ties into their narrative that the GOP is not the party of getting things done, but the party of Trump and obstructionism.

Comment: @IanKemp Make sure you read carefully the second paragraph of the quote. The Democrats might "score" politically by being unable to stop the Republicans from causing terrible harm, but that's clearly not sensible from a "do least harm" point of view, nor is it guaranteed that if terrible things happen in the next two years, this won't come back to haunt Biden even if he is pointing to a Republican Congress and saying "it's their fault."

Comment: In hindsight, the answer to most Qs in the last para (of the quote) was "yes."

Answer (score 6):

It is hard to say at this point in time because of various agendas that have been put forward for a Republican controlled house are things that Democrats don't want to happen. While it is true that whoever gets elected may go forward with those agenda items regardless there is no need for Democrats to help them happen sooner.

[Impeach Biden](https://www.theatlantic.com/ideas/archive/2022/10/republicans-investigate-possible-impeachment-joe-biden/671859/)

[Investigate Biden (and son)](https://www.ny1.com/nyc/all-boroughs/politics/2022/11/17/house-republicans-announce-investigation-into-biden--accuse-of-him-direct-involvement-in-hunter-s-business-affairs)

Those are both things that Democrats are not going to be too keen to get started.

Comment: The first link doesn't talk about impeaching Joe Biden himself. It talks about impeaching Alejandro Mayorkas, Biden's Secretary of Homeland Security.

Comment: @Philipp Though there are efforts to [impeach biden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efforts_to_impeach_Joe_Biden), including house resolutions (mostly by Marjorie Taylor Greene, with the most prominent - having 6 co-sponsors - being from Lauren Boebert). Not sure if it's a mainstream goal in the Republican party, but at least Ted Cruz seems to think so ("whether it's justified or not") and The Hill called it a "top priority".

Comment: @Philipp That was the first link for a search on impeach Biden and it seems I didn't look at it close enough so I have updated it to a new link.

Comment: @JoeW That article is an opinion-piece that begins with "This may not be their present plan, but they will work themselves up to it by degrees". The author admits that a possible Biden impeachment is just his personal prediction for the future and not already on the Republican agenda.

Comment: @Philipp I am confused at what you are looking for as it has been all over the news since well before the election that there is talk about Republicans wanting to impeach Biden. I am not sure if it matters that this is an opinion piece as that doesn't change the fear that Democrats have of what Republican's are planning to do in this congress.

Comment: The first sentence is run-on. Sorry, I wouldn't normally complain about that, but I found it difficult to understand. You could either get rid of the "of" or add "which" to make *"which are things ..."*.

Comment: So you're saying McCarthy is a notable proponent of these agendas, right? I'm not sure if I'm having a brain fart or if I'm missing context since I'm not American. I skimmed the links and the first one says he's in favour of investigation and could be swayed towards impeaching.

Comment: @wjandrea I am not saying that McCarthy is or anyone in general is just that it has been brought up many times during and after the election as an agenda item that will be done if they control the house.